# Set default duration in res_config

Tags: python, default, odoo

I have a module that has, a creation date (of course, the day it was created) and a deadline date.

The thing is that I want to be able to set a default value to this deadline date according to the date it was created. 
But I want to be able to configurate this dynamically from (lets say) res_config.

e.g.

If I configured the default values in res_config to 5 days, I want the default value for the deadline date to be populated with a date 5 days ahead of the creation date.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this using the model `ir.configure_parameter`.

In res_config.py:

```
class my_configuration(osv.osv_memory):
    _inherit = ['res.confi.settings']
    _columns = {
       'default_deadline' : fields.integer('Days per default', help="""Help field"""),
    }
    ...
    def set_default_deadline(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        config = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
        config = config and config[0]
        val = '%s' %(config.default_deadline) or '10'
        self.pool.geet('ir.config_parameter').set_param(cr,uid, 'key_value', val)
        return True
```

Whit this we have created a system parameter. It is actually created as a mapping from 'key_value' to val that is a string, so we will have to cast it to the desired type when necessary.
In my case, y created a function to get the deadline date in my module:

```
def _get_deadline_date(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    val = self.pool.get('ir.config_parameter').get_param(cr, uid, 'key_value')
    try:
        val = int(val)
    except: 
        # Just in case...
        val = 30
    return (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=val)).strftime('%Y,%m,%d')

_defaults = {
    'deadline_date': lambda s, cr, uid, c: s._get_deadline_date(self, cr, uid,     context=c),
}
```

Thank you, hope it helps!